# Patenting an already created product

Tags: product, already, patented, college, student

I recently had an amazing product idea, and unfortunately, I found out the product is already being patented. My question is, can I create and produce an already patented product?

For example, there are hundreds of different that produce umbrellas, yet that is an already patented product, so how can a new company begin manufacturing umbrellas if they are already patented?

I'm a college student looking to patent and produce a new product, and I want to receive information and tips in a step-by-step manner on how I can move forward with this idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't patent something that has already be invented by someone else. You also do not need a patent to produce a product. You only need to make sure that your product doesn't infringe on existing patents. With regards to umbrellas, many of those patents are probably expired by now and as such free to use.

If you see a patent that you think is relevant to a product you want to produce, first thing is to check to see if is issued and then carefully read it. Remember, the claims are what define what is patented. Although they cost money, patent lawyers are an important part of the process. As you are a college student, your college may provide support in this area.